# How to set stacked bar chart series color dynamically?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a stacked bar chart in JasperSoft 6.3.1 in eclipse and I am trying to display the colors based on the series. The chart displays random colors instead of assigning a single color for a specific series.

**jrxml**

```
<categorySeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{time}]]></categoryExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
</categorySeries>
</categoryDataset>
    <barPlot>
        <plot>
            <seriesColor $F{name}.equals("JANUARY")?color="#756D72":color="" seriesOrder="0" />
            <seriesColor $F{name}.equals("MARCH")?color="#4B5154":color="" seriesOrder="1" />
            <seriesColor $F{name}.equals("JUNE")?color="#090A09":color="" seriesOrder="2"/>
        </plot>
    <itemLabel/>
    <categoryAxisFormat>
    ....
```

I am trying to assign the chart series color to a specific series name using the if statement. How do I achieve this in jasper reports?.

> If the series name is JANUARY the color should be black, and if there is no data for JANUARY the black color should not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I guess that you have noticed, you can **not** do if statements in the xml tags, the jrxml will simple not compile since it's not valid xml anymore.

The solution is to implement your own [**`JRChartCustomizer`**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html)

## Example

**java**

Find the different series name and set `Paint` to the renderer on basis of the name

```
public class BarColorCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart jfchart, JRChart jrchart) {
        //Get the plot
        CategoryPlot  plot = jfchart.getCategoryPlot();
        //Get the dataset
        CategoryDataset dataSet = plot.getDataset();
        //Loop the row count (our series)
        int rowCount = dataSet.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            Comparable<?> rowKey = dataSet.getRowKey(i);
            //Get a custom paint for our series key
            Paint p = getCustomPaint(rowKey);
            if (p!=null){
                //set the new paint to the renderer
                plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(i, p);
            }
        }

    }

    //Example of simple implementation returning Color on basis of value
    private Paint getCustomPaint(Comparable<?> rowKey) {
        if ("JANUARY".equals(rowKey)){
            return Color.BLACK;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**jrxml**

Set the `customizerClass` attribute with full package name on the chart tag

```
<barChart>
    <chart evaluationTime="Report" customizerClass="my.custom.BarColorCustomizer">
    ....
</barChart>
```

Comment: woow that works perfect. you saved my day. i had gone through a lot of links and i could not find a solution. Sorry to ask again is it possible to hide the category color bar if it is empty.

Comment: @joseph hide the category color bar?, category is a group of series?, I can't really understand what you mean, anyway you can set color of bar and outline as you like even on value, hence set it as background and you will not see it ;)

Comment: @ Petter Friberg thank you very much. you have answered me correctly, i wanted to set the empty category as background.

Comment: great solution... and if you want to set your color from an RGB string, see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Convertsagivenstringintoacolor.htm